# DSolve appears to give wrong solution

Tags: differential-equations, physics

I'm trying to solve a linear system of ODEs:

```
DSolve[{D[c1m[y], y] == 0, D[c2m[y], y] == 2 I kf c3p[y], 
  D[c2p[y], y] == 2 I kf c3m[y], -D[c2m[y], y] - A == 0,
  D[c1m[y], y] - D[c3m[y], y] == 2 I kf c2p[y],
  2 D[c0[y], y] - D[c2p[y], y] - B == 0,
  D[c1p[y], y] - D[c3p[y], y] == 2 I kf c2m[y]},
 {c1m[y], c1p[y], c2m[y], c2p[y], c3m[y], c3p[y], c0[y]}, {y}]
```

Note that `A`, `B` and `kf` have dimensions of 1/space, and that the different c's are dimensionless whereas `y` has a space dimension so that this set of ODEs is valid. However, the answer I get for `c1p` is dimensionally wrong (involves adding space dimension with space squared).

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: The dimensional analysis also carries through if `y` and the parameters are treated as dimensionless. Indeed, the system is autonomous and therefore mathematically invariant under the transformation $y\rightarrow y+3$, where $3$ could be any other real number.   Try `Expand[soln]`. One of the terms you identified cancels out (at least what I identified from your description). However, you'll still have a constant term `6 I kf C[6]` that is supposed to be dimensionless. Try `Simplify[soln]` and maybe you can justify `3 + y` as having the same dimensions as `y`. Not sure it can be fixed.

Comment: Indeed, the problem is having the `y+3` as `3` is obviously dimensionless and can't be justified from the equations (which keep the dimensional requirement). Also, it's unclear to me where this `3` stems from.

Comment: Substituting the `DSolve` result into the ODEs yields `{True, True, True, True, True, True, True}`, so the result appears to  be correct.

Comment: How did you check? I used `FullSimplify[eqn/.soln]` and it doesn't yield as you write. Regardless, I agree that Mathematica thinks it's correct. However, I'm trying to figure out how or why because it's uncanny to give up dimensional analisys like that.

Comment: Use `DSolve[{D[c1m[y], y] == 0, D[c2m[y], y] == 2 I kf c3p[y], D[c2p[y], y] == 2 I kf c3m[y], -D[c2m[y], y] - A == 0, D[c1m[y], y] - D[c3m[y], y] == 2 I kf c2p[y], 
   2 D[c0[y], y] - D[c2p[y], y] - B == 0, D[c1p[y], y] - D[c3p[y], y] == 2 I kf c2m[y]}, {c1m, c1p, c2m, c2p, c3m, c3p, c0}, y] // Flatten` to obtain `Function`s as solutions.  Then use `Simplify[{ ... }/.{ ... }]` where first `...` is your list of equations and the second `...` is the solution you just obtained.  Hope this helps.

Comment: By the way, when you reply to a comment, include the user name so that your intended recipient receives a notice.  For instance, @bbgodfrey.

Comment: Here's a subset with the same issue: `DSolve[{
  D[c2m[y], y] == 2 I kf c3p[y],
  -D[c2m[y], y] - A == 0,
  D[c1p[y], y] - D[c3p[y], y] == 2 I kf c2m[y]},
 {c2m[y], c1p[y], c3p[y]}, y
 ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach that avoids the units ambiguity is to solve the first 5 equations and then solve the other 2 equations, like this

```
deqs = {
   D[c1m[y], y] == 0,
   D[c2m[y], y] == 2 I kf c3p[y],
   D[c2p[y], y] == 2 I kf c3m[y],
   -D[c2m[y], y] - A == 0,
   D[c1m[y], y] - D[c3m[y], y] == 2 I kf c2p[y],
   2 D[c0[y], y] - D[c2p[y], y] - B == 0,
   D[c1p[y], y] - D[c3p[y], y] == 2 I kf c2m[y]};

soln = First@DSolve[deqs[[1 ;; 5]],
    {c1m[y], c2m[y], c2p[y], c3m[y], c3p[y]}, y];

dsoln := soln /. Rule[lhs_, rhs_] :> (D[lhs, y] -> D[rhs, y]);

soln = Join[soln, First@DSolve[deqs[[{6, 7}]] /. soln /. dsoln,
     {c1p[y], c0[y]}, y]];

soln // ColumnForm // TeXForm
```

$\begin{array}{c}
 \text{c1m}(y)\to c_1 \\
 \text{c2p}(y)\to c_2 \cosh (2
   \text{kf} y)+i c_3 \sinh (2
   \text{kf} y) \\
 \text{c3m}(y)\to c_3 \cosh (2
   \text{kf} y)-i c_2 \sinh (2
   \text{kf} y) \\
 \text{c2m}(y)\to c_4-A y \\
 \text{c3p}(y)\to \frac{i A}{2
   \text{kf}} \\
 \text{c0}(y)\to \frac{B
   y}{2}+c_5+\frac{1}{2} c_2 \cosh (2
   \text{kf} y)+\frac{1}{2} i c_3 \sinh
   (2 \text{kf} y) \\
 \text{c1p}(y)\to c_6-2 i \text{kf}
   \left(\frac{A y^2}{2}-y c_4\right)
   \\
\end{array}$

Besides having no ambiguity in the solution for `c1p[y]`, this approach yields hyperbolic trig functions, which can be easier to interpret than several exponentials.

#### Checking this solution

Replace the solutions and the derivatives of the solutions and check

```
deqs /. soln /. dsoln // Simplify

(*  {True, True, True, True, True, True, True}  *)
```

#### Original ambiguity

Note:  the constants `C[5]` and `C[6]` found below are not the same as those above.

When we solve all 7 DEs at once, the solution for `c1p[y]` contains an ambiguity

```
amb = c1p[y] /. First@DSolve[deqs,
                {c1m[y], c1p[y], c2m[y], c2p[y], c3m[y], c3p[y], c0[y]}, y];

amb // Simplify 

(*  A (I/(2 kf) - I kf y^2) + C[5] + 2 I kf (3 + y) C[6]  *)
```

The `y+3` term looks ambiguous, since $y$ has units and 3 does not, but the 3 can be consolidated into the constant $c_5$ by introducing the initial condition `c1p[0]` like this

```
amb /. First@First@Solve[
         (Last[amb] /. y -> 0) == c1p[0], C[5]] // Simplify

(*  c1p[y] -> -I A kf y^2 + 2 I kf y C[6] + c1p[0]  *)
```

Or by introducing a new constant, `C[7]`

```
amb[[-1]] = amb[[-1]] + C[7] - (amb[[-1]] /. y -> 0) // Simplify;
amb

(*  c1p[y] -> -I A kf y^2 + 2 I kf y C[6] + C[7]  *)
```

#### How many ODEs are there?

We count 7 DEs in the list, but there are only 6 arbitrary constants.  Taken as a separate system, the second and fourth DE's give an algebraic solution for `c3p[y]` without a constant of integration.